# Push navigator views from within actionscript class (FlexMobile)

Tags: ios, apache-flex, mobile, actionscript

This time I need to change the view of a mobile application from inside an actionscript itemRenderer. I dont have access to the navigator.push(view) function so im stuck. Should I dispatch an event to application to do that ? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Dispatch an event from the renderer; and make sure it bubbles.  You may want to dispatch a custom event that includes data from the renderer.  Listen for that event in the view and make your relevant changes in the listener.